# EJB Object reference Declarations as Class Member Field vs. Method Local Variable

Tags: java, oop, ejb, ejb-3.0

I have a class, where I use multiple EJB manager objects. Each time when a new manager is needed, I usually add them as a class member field bearing in mind that it might be used in other methods as well. Something like this:

```
public class SomeClass {
    @EJB
    private XManager xManager;

    @EJB
    private YManager yManager;

    ..........................

    public void method1() {
        // uses xManager and/or yManager
    }

    public void method2() {
        // uses yManager
    }

    ........................
}
```

**my question** is: Is there any difference if I declare those EJB object references locally in each method? That will affect on garbage collection, but might it affect on something else, like performance, best practices, etc.?

Comment: How do you plan to "declare those EJB object references locally in each method"?

Comment: In order for the DI to work, you have to get an instance of your bean when the object is instantiated, there is no clean way to get it when the method is called.

Comment: I also have a factory class which has lookup method(s) and returns the runtime **EJB** objects with the help of **InitialContext.lookup()** method.

Comment: What kind of EJBs are SomeClass and the injected EJBs? Singleton, SLSB, SFSB?

Comment: All are stateless. Does it make any difference?

Comment: the only thing that comes to mind would be a performance hit of doing the lookup on every method invocation, versus the lookup only happening when the proxy is first created (assuming the pool is depleted and no other existing proxies are available to execute the request).  but this depends on how often you are executing these methods in question.